# Installing Visual Studio

Tags: windows, installation, visual-studio-2010

When installing Visual Studio on Windows machine, it always installs a plenty of annoying things. If there were a few programs in the list of programs before installing Visual Studio, after it it will grow by a few times. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: Which "annoying things"?

Comment: Visual Studio installed 48 applications as a part of it.

Comment: You didn't try to install custom.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure pretty sure that either they are necessary or can be removed by doing a custom install. I don't see any reason for Microsoft to install 48 applications for no reason.

Comment: it's Microsoft - its policy is "The more Microsoft on your computer is, the better it is"